# Left Button doing Right Click in Windows

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, mouse, touchpad

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3567 (laptop) running Windows 10. It has a touchpad. Everything was fine until I formatted (reinstalled windows on) it. After that, I rebooted first time and was surprised to see that simply tapping on touchpad does right-click. Clicking on touchpad also do Right-Click. Left button on touchpad also do right-click, BUT Right button on touchpad does left-click? Why is the action inverted, and how do I fix it?

**What I have tried (None of those worked):**

- Installing Drivers for touchpad.
- Uninstalling and re-installing touchpad driver.
- Rebooting the PC, trying out from another user.
- Checking online for solutions.

**And What I haven't tried:**

- Connecting external mouse.
- Checking in another OS (live boot).

And because its a touchpad, it is really hard to control such device, Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a setting in Windows:

1. Open Settings ( <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> )
2. Devices --> Mouse
3. Open Additional Mouse settings
4. Here, toggle from Left-Handed to Right-handed.

[image]

Comment: Thank You VERY VERY much! It worked 100%!